# mysql slow in date filter on big table

Tags: mysql

i have a big table with over 10 million records, I've change the engine from InnoDB to MyISAM after that i've got better performance on `count` function but below query take about 3 - 4 seconds to run :

simple count :

```
select count(`id`) from sample_table ;
```

takes about 2 mili seconds

```
SELECT count(`id`) from sample_table where created_at > '2015-06-24 19:26:08';
```

takes about 3 - 4 seconds

I've add index for created_at field but that dosen't help to increase the performance.

my goal is to make it run in maximum of 1 second ! please help me to make it possible.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see what exactly MySQL is doing.

Comment: Try using TIMESTAMP('2015-06-24 19:26:08') and, if that doesn't help, make created_at a timestamp (with index).

Comment: @Mike after using timestamp run time enhanced from 2.8 sec to 2.4 sec but still dose not meet my goal.

Comment: Is there an index on `created_at`?

Comment: @Wallyk Yes. but the run time dose not have any major change with or without the index.

Comment: What happens if you use count(created_at)? That should push all the processing into the index file, ignoring the table altogether and should be as fast as you can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few things to try.

I *think* MySQL is going to scan the index to count the records, rather than just using the index metadata to get the total records. So, 3-4 seconds to scan an index for 10 million records isn't *that* long.

Although it should not make a difference, perhaps a `count(*)` would optimize better:

```
SELECT count(*)
from sample_table
where created_at > '2015-06-24 19:26:08';
```

It is also worth trying a `>=` just to see if there is a difference.

Comment: Thanks gordon but >= dose not help nor count(*)

Comment: It is frustrating because I think the index has (or could have at least) the right information in its hierarchy (child counts).  However, the query doesn't seem to be using the information.  Right now, I can't think of a way to avoid the index scan.

Comment: I'm sorry you are right changin count(`id`) to count(*) makes it run in 0.24 sec and i got the desire result. Thanks. but would you please explain why changing to count(*) makes it faster ?